# SSAS CUBE Calculated member based on different members in dimension and different measures

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I am new to SSAS, I am creating a cube and I need to have a calculated member.The complexity is I have property name as one dimension which has members like "a,b,c,d". Each of this member will be having one value per date in a measure called 'property value'.

I have another measure "Volume" which will be one value per day(date dimension).

I need to do calculation of (a*volume + b* volume) as a calculated member.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer which is very simple, using tuple we can access measure value for a particular dimension member as,

([Measures].[PropertyValue],[Property].[PropertyName])

Answer (score 1):

I would try a Measure expression of:

`[Measures].[property value] * [Measures].[Volume]`

If those source measures have AggregateFunction set to Sum, then the aggregation will happen automatically.

Comment: Thank you Mike, But I said just two measures there to explain the problem in simple way, but I have 3 measures(the 2 volume measures) 4 dimension members in same dimension involved in it. The calculation is little bit complex than just multiplying and adding.

Comment: I am trying to explain my question more clear,   Dimension "PropertyName", Let's say it's members a,b,c,d.  There are 3 measures, Property Value, Prod Volume, Inj Volume. Property value measure is related to property name dimension and date dimension, where other two measures are just tied to date dimension. Now using these details, I am trying to create a calculation like,    (a.prodvolume)+(b.Inj Volume) /(c.InjVolume +d.Prodvolume) for each date, should I create a measure calculated member or dimensional calculated member, please advice.